# Save output from multiple loops matlab

Tags: matlab

Hello I have 3 variables i,j and k. I want to run a loop on each of them such that for each value of i, one value of j is considered and iterated over all values of k.Then for same i, take second value of j and iterate over all values of k and so on... Then repeat this process for all the values of i and save the output. For example for i=1,j=1 iterate over all values of k.Then for i=1, j=2 iterate over all values of k so on. Then save the output m for all the values of i and j over k iterations.

```
for i=1:30
for j=1:5
for k=1:100
    m=i*0.5*j*sin(k);
end
end
end
```

May be my code is not right as well?

Comment: Many thanks for your time but that's not what I am looking for. I have edited my question in more detail. Can you please check if you have time.  Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) you can accomplish this without any explicit `for` loops:

```
[i,j,k] = ndgrid(1:30,1:5,1:100);
m = 0.5*i.*j.*sin(k);
```

Or with [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) if you flip the first two inputs:

```
[j,i,k] = meshgrid(1:5,1:30,1:100);
m = 0.5*i.*j.*sin(k);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time but that's not what I am looking for. I have edited my question in more detail. Can you please check if you have time.  Many Thanks

Comment: @bilal: This code exactly replicates the output of the code in your question (except that it stores all values for each combination of `i`, `j`, and `k` in a 3-D array). You need to update that too. The updated text in your question is not clear at all.

Comment: Perhaps my code is not right. I want to find m for i=1,j=1 over k iterations, then i=1,j=2 and for all values of k and so on. Does this make any sense?

Comment: `[i,j,k] = ndgrid(1:30,1:5,1:100);` `m = 0.5*i.*j.*sin(k);` then `m(1,1,:)` is a vector for i=1, j=1, and all values of `k` (1 to 100). From your description, I don't see what else you could want.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing you can do is to define `m` as a 3D `array`; also, since you know in advance the final size of the `array` you can initialize it before the loops to avoid MatLab allocating the memory at each iteration:

```
% Initialize the array
m=zeros(30,5,100);
for i=1:30
   for j=1:5
      for k=1:100
         % Set the values in the array "m"
         m(i,j,k)=i*0.5*j*sin(k);
      end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

In case you want, for each `i` and `j` the value of `m` be computed over `k` iterations, the variable `m` should be present also on the right of the `=` sign.

It should, for example, be somenthing like:

```
m=m+i+j+k
```

you can try the following modified version of the above code

```
% Initialize the array
m=zeros(30,5);
for i=1:30
   for j=1:5
      % Initialize the temporary varaible at each iteration
      tmp_var=0;
      for k=1:100
         % Compute the value of "tmp_var" over "k" iteration
         tmp_var=tmp_var+i*0.5*j*sin(k);
      end
      % Assign the value of "tmp_var" computed for a given (i,j) couple
      m(i,j)=tmp_var;
  end
end
```

In this example you need to define a temporary varaible to be used inside the `k` loop; at the end of the `k` loop the value of the temporary variable will be stored in the `m` matrix.

At the end of the script, you will have a matrix `m` of size (30 x 5).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for your time but that's not what I am looking for. I have edited my question in more detail. Can you please check if you have time.  Many Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately the additional information you've added are not clear: for a given value of `i` and `j` does the value of `m` at the `k` iteration somehow depend on the value of `m` at the `(k-1)` iteration?

Comment: Perhaps my code is not right. I want to find m for i=1,j=1 over k iterations, then i=1,j=2 and for all values of k and so on. Does this make any sense?

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope I've undersood you need.

Comment: Thanks for your update. But tmp-var value is added on every iteration of k ? I want to get all the values of k . Does it make any sence?  Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In cases where the computation in the loop is only depending on the loop index you could just write:

```
[j,i,k]=meshgrid(1:5,1:30,1:100);
m=.5*i.*j.*sin(k);
```

meshgrid will create the appropriate 3D arrays of the indices i,j,k and m will be of the same dimension when the elementwise multiplication (.* instead of *) is used.

Comment: Many thanks for your time but that's not what I am looking for. I have edited my question in more detail. Can you please check if you have time.  Many Thanks